# Android SQLite trying to update one field

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My code is below, but it crashes my application. I'm still pretty new with working with db, but it seems to make sense. Any signs of why this could be not working?

```
 public void updateLevel(String level){
             mDb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_CUR_LEVEL + " = " + level + " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = Default", null);
         }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Default` is interpreted as a column name; if it is a string, you have to use `'Default'`.

To avoid formatting problem like this, it is recommended to use parameters, which are written in the SQL command as `?`. They get their value from the corresponding entry in the second parameter of `rawQuery` (or similar parameters of other SQL functions).
This is easier than putting `'` around strings, remembering to escape `'` inside strings, and makes using strings with control characters possible.

```java
mDb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ DATABASE_TABLE +
             " SET " + KEY_CUR_LEVEL + " = " + level +
             " WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = ?",
             new String[] { "Default" });
```

Comment: Perfect. Your first suggesstion worked. I'm not sure what you mean by using parameters. Care to explain?

Comment: I suggest paramaterizing `level` as well to avoid SQL injection

Comment: @CJBS The Android database API has only string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I see two issues:

1) Using rawQuery is discuoraged due to SQL injections. If possible use [SQLiteDatabase query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

2) If the columns are of type varchar, values should be in single quote.

Example:

```
mDb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ DATABASE_TABLE + " SET " + KEY_CUR_LEVEL + " = '" + level + "' WHERE " + KEY_NAME + " = 'Default'", null);
```

NOTE: Above query is hand typed there may be syntax errors.

Comment: APpreciate the input, but since I'm not taking text from the user, I don't believe I have to worry about SQL injections.

Comment: @EGHDK: SQL Injection is not just because of user input, it may be case if any special characters are already stored in for that key. If you are not too sensitive for that issue, you may ignore and continue with point 2 fix.

Answer (score 1):

I find that using the [update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method is a little less prone to human error.

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(KEY_CUR_LEVEL, level);

mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, "? = ?", new String[] { KEY_NAME, "Default"});
```

Comment: Column names cannot be used as parameters.

Comment: +1 to both CL and Vyrx.  I wouldn't use a placeholder (?) for the column name but in general, I also find using this part of the API preferable over `rawQuery()`.